# GPU becomes unavailable when computer goes to sleep

Tags: docker, tensorflow, gpu, jupyter-notebook

I am using docker installation of [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation) .

I initiate the container using

```
nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /*/Data/docker:/docker --name TensorFlow   gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu /bin/bash
```

This allows me to link a folder names "docker" in my secondary local drive with a folder inside docker container.

The issue is that whenever my computer (Ubuntu - GTX 1070 - 6700k Intel CPU) goes to sleep, the GPU becomes unavailable and code runs only on CPU. When I run the code in ipython notebook session inside docker I get:

> failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN.

```
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
   E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:153] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: 123456c234ds
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:160] hostname: 123456c234ds
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:185] libcuda reported version is: 367.57.0
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:356] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  367.57  Mon Oct  3 20:37:01 PDT 2016
    GCC version:  gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) 
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] kernel reported version is: 367.57.0
   I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:293] kernel version seems to match DSO: 367.57.0
```

When i restart the computer, the GPU becomes available without the UNKNOWN message.

I have searched the Internet and the solutions such as `sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Your GPU just doesn't like to be sharply woken up.